# Passing constructor variables

Tags: php, constructor, extends

So I have a class that extends another class. Here is my code as follows. The main class is Model. Then I have another class create_user_model that extends Method.

```
//Model Class//
class Model {

private $connection;
private $connstring;

public function __construct(){

$this->connection = new createConnection();         //create connection object

$this->connstring = $this->connection->connectToDatabase();

}}
```

Then I have my Create User Model that extends model.

```
/// Create_User_Model///

class Create_User_Model extends Model {
private $connection;
private $connstring;
private $sql;

function __construct() {
  parent:: __construct();
}

public function create_user(){

//Want to get rid of these two lines and get $this->connstring from constructor//
$this->connection = new createConnection(); //create connection object
$this->connstring = $this->connection->connectToDatabase();

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('John', 'James')";

if ($this->connstring->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $this->connstring->error;
 }
 }
 }
```

Notice how I constructed the Model in the constructor of the Create_User_Model. So now I should have access the the variables $this->connection and $this->connstring in the function create_user(or at least what I thought), but i don't know how to access them. You can see I had to create a connection object again in function create_user create the connstring all over and then there is no point of having a constructor. I was wondering How I could get this information from the constructor so I can take the first two lines out in the create user function. Hope what I am asking makes any sense. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Private variables can only be used within the class where they are declared.
Protected variables can be used in their own class and any class extensions.
Public variables can be accessed from anywhere.

Change your attributes in Model from private to protected.

Comment: Manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea about any of those rules.  Saved me a bunch of time.